# Handling target-specific scripts, such as users, logins and permissions

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

How do I best handle deployment of for example permissions that are different on different target environments? For example users, logins and permissions. I am now using manually created script files like this:

```
  IF @@SERVERNAME='DEV'
      -- dev environment code
  IF @@SERVERNAME='PROD'
      -- prod environment code
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it through Publish profiles using different SSDT variables. That way if I have several different servers that could be "Production", I don't have a servername hard-coded in the project.  I blogged about it here: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/05/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per.html

(Credit to Jamie Thomson for the original idea.)

Comment: Thank's, Peter. Seems basically a similar solution but your solution is more elegant, with SSDT variables where we have a set of hard-coded targets.